# Nearest Neighbors Classification in scitkit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand and use [this code from the scikit learn site](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#example-neighbors-plot-classification-py):

I've changed X to

```
X = [[ 170,  70 ], [ 180,  80  ], [ 190,  90 ], [ 200,  100], [ 172,  80 ], [ 182,  72 ], [ 185,  95 ], [ 184,  74 ], [ 184,  80 ], [ 177,  67 ], [ 177,  77 ], [ 177,  87 ],
     [ 190,  85 ], [ 190,  86  ], [ 190,  97 ], [ 190,  82 ], [ 190,  84 ], [ 195,  85 ], [ 185,  92 ], [ 185,  77 ], [ 183,  87 ], [ 183,  77 ], [ 183,  78 ], [ 182,  88 ],
     [ 177,  78 ], [ 177,  82  ], [ 176,  70 ], [ 172,  65 ], [ 170,  62 ], [ 170,  68 ], [ 173,  65 ], [ 173,  64 ], [ 168,  71 ], [ 169,  62 ], [ 174,  80 ], [ 173,  65 ],
     [ 180,  100], [ 180,  60  ], [ 170,  90 ], [ 170,  55 ], [ 180,  68 ], [ 175,  92 ], [ 168,  100], [ 177,  110], [ 180,  110], [ 186,  65 ], [ 186,  145], [ 190,  120],
     [ 175,  55 ], [ 182,  65  ], [ 195,  70 ], [ 173,  90 ], [ 175,  50 ], [ 182,  130], [ 183,  65 ], [ 150,  82 ], [ 155,  80 ], [ 200,  70 ], [ 185,  110], [ 176,  100]]
```

which is the height and weight as a training data set.

I've also changed y to

```
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which is acceptable - not acceptable, my two classes.

How do I test a new case like [140, 85] to see if it is 1 or 0?

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

in the example uses the same data as the training data an it's computation is based on the min, max and step of the training data set, which is confusing. Any help please.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do here?  Can you provide some more context?  Is this giving you an error?  What's your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have linked is so complicated because it also creates the plot you see on the site.

Without the plot it is as simple as calling

```
result = clf.predict([140,85])
```

to get your result of your new sample [140, 85].

To summarize, all you really need is the following:

```
from sklearn import neighbors

# Define your X and y here

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(5)
clf.fit(X, y)
result = clf.predict([140,85])
```

The parameter for the classifier (in my example 5) describes how many neighbors should be considered for the prediction. Play around with this number until you get a nice result.

Comment: Thank you Robin but how can I plot as well?

Comment: @jimakos17 up to which line do you understand what's happening? They basically create a mesh which encompasses all datapoint and predict the target class for each point in the mesh. Then they plot the mesh with the prediction as color.

Comment: The point of the [140,85] that I create is supposed to be in the mesh, specifically in the red side. How can I include the result, as you name it, in the mesh? I suppose in the plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light) after the result = clf.predict([140,85]) Thank you Robin!

Comment: The points are plotted with the plt.scatter function. To plot the [140, 85] point you can use `plt.scatter(140,85, c=result, cmap=cmap_bold)` where result is the prediction for the point. (And cmap_bold is defined in the example)

Comment: Thank you Robin for your prompt, clear and concise answers. Thank you very much!!!